# how to get the user id in signed_request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ but when I try out the code displayed there and print out the data by print_r() there is no key or variable of "user_id", also the article claims that.

Answer (score 2):

Right underneath the table the documentation says:

> If the user has not authorized your application, your application will
>   only be passed a subset of the above information.

Facebook won't give you the user id if the user has not authorized your app. The same happens when using the PHP SDK method `getUser()`. If the user has not given you basic permissions, you don't know who he is.

Comment: But how addmefast.com validates facebook likes then(they don't have authorization)?